# Two segments Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let consider the set composed by two intersecting segments of $R^2$.

Is it (sub)-manifold ?

Thanks

Comment: If they intersect on a cross pattern, then no.

Comment: What would a coordinate patch containing the intersection of the two lines look like?

Comment: I was thinking that the patch on the cross will be homeomorphic to $R^2$ and the other patch to $R^1$ ... but the dimension is not well defined